# Sharepoint 2010 SPServices

Tags: list, jquery, spservices

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and SPServices to retrieve the elements of a list, but no all items,

**My list have these fields:**

- Year: calculated column
- Month: Choice column
- Company: Line of text
- Department: Choice Column
- Type: Choice Column
- Cost: Line of text

I want to filter the list by **Year, Month, Company, Department,** and **Type**
so this is the code:

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "{list guid}", 
        viewName: "{view guid}",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Cost' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery:"<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year'/><Value Type='Integer'>2016</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Month' /><Value Type='Integer'>11</Value></Eq></And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Company' /><Value Type='Text'>CompanyName</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department' /><Value Type='Text'>IT</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Type' /><Value Type='Text'>two</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var liHtml =$(this).attr("ows_Title");
                var Cost =$(this).attr("ows_Cost");

                });

        }
    });
```

My problem is that a can't retrieve anything and the next step with all the items retrieved o want to sum all there **Cost**  values 
If you guys can help me I really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the columns in view fields which are being used in Filters(CAMLQuery).

To sum up the cost, once you receive you can loop through item and use simple mathematical calculations. Below is modified code which may get you started..

```
$().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "{list guid}", 
        viewName: "{view guid}",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Cost' /><FieldRef Name='Year'/><FieldRef Name='Month'/><FieldRef Name='Company'/><FieldRef Name='Department'/><FieldRef Name='Type'/></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery:"<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year'/><Value Type='Integer'>2016</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Month' /><Value Type='Integer'>11</Value></Eq></And><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Company' /><Value Type='Text'>CompanyName</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department' /><Value Type='Text'>IT</Value></Eq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Type' /><Value Type='Text'>two</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
         var Cost =0;
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var liHtml =$(this).attr("ows_Title");
                Cost += $(this).attr("ows_Cost");

                });

        }
    });
```